# Referencing column header component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm building a datatable, and trying to block an entire column of cells when a button in the header is clicked.

```
<p:dataTable id="table" var="data"
             value="#{bean.data}"
             rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
    <p:columns var="columnName" id="columnId" columnIndexVar="colIndex" value="#{bean.columns}" width="240">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:commandButton value="Test"
                             id="headerButton"
                             update="d"
                             style="width: 60px"
                             actionListener="#{bean.doThing(columnName)}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <p:outputPanel id="cell" style="display:block">
            <h:outputText value="#{data.displayText}"/>

            <p:blockUI block="cell" trigger="table:columnName:#{colIndex}:headerButton">
                <p:graphicImage name="loading.gif"/>
            </p:blockUI>>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

I expected this code to work, with the trigger being the of the header button, but I'm getting an error when the page loads, I think because the system is searching asking for a row index between 'table' and 'columnName' in the trigger.

Is there a way to reference the id of the button header from the blocking component here?

Comment: did you try to rendred it or you need to show the information and diseable any action ?!?

Comment: And post WHAT error you get...